# ¿Cómo eliminar elementos de un XML con XSLT?

Tags: html, xml

Estoy desarrollando un sistema donde se puedan gestionar los recursos educativos (planeaciones, documentos como *pdf*, videos, y demás, asociados a las planeaciones). Sin embargo, requiero tener la posibilidad de que cada usuario que se encuentre registrado en el sistema, pueda ver, modificar y eliminar las planeaciones que él ha creado.

Cuando se crean las planeaciones, inmediatamente se registran en un índice creado en XML, que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
<indicePlaneacion>    
    <planeacion>
        <claveUea>2151075</claveUea>
        <nombreUea>Introducción a la Programación para Ingenieros</nombreUea>
        <trimestre>15-P</trimestre>
        <fechaActualizacion>2016-05-30</fechaActualizacion>
        <profesor>
            <nombre>Martha </nombre>
            <apellidoPaterno>Rodriguez </apellidoPaterno>
            <apellidoMaterno>Cáliz</apellidoMaterno>
        </profesor>
        <uri>/PLAN/Datos/xml/planeacion/2151075-15-P-CD02.xml</uri>
    </planeacion>
    <planeacion>
        <claveUea>2151123</claveUea>
        <nombreUea>BASES DE DATOS</nombreUea>
        <trimestre>16-P</trimestre>
        <fechaActualizacion>2016-06-01</fechaActualizacion>
        <profesor>
            <nombre>JUAN</nombre>
            <apellidoPaterno>ZARATE</apellidoPaterno>
            <apellidoMaterno>RODRIGUEZ</apellidoMaterno>
        </profesor>
        <uri>/PLAN/Datos/xml/planeacion/2151123-16-P-CI01.xml</uri>
    </planeacion>
    .
    .
    .
</indicePlaneacion>
```

¿Cómo eliminar las planeaciones usando un XSL?
A lo que me refiero, es que el usuario puede ver las planeaciones todos los usuarios han agregado, sin embargo, solo puede eliminar las que el ha agregado. Para eliminarlas, es necesario eliminar el registro planeacion (con todos sus nodos hijos en cuestión) y eliminar el archivo especificado en la uri.

Con php se eliminaria el archivo de la uri pero el registro dentro del xml sería con xsl, sin embargo no sé como eliminarlo. Si alguien pudiese ayudarme, le agradecería demasiado.

El sistema está desarrollado con php 5.6.

Comment: 'XSL' (Extensible Stylesheet Language) establece cómo será formateado el documento XML. Si quieres modificar el documento XML (para eliminar un elemento 'planeacion', por ejemplo) deberás decir en qué lenguaje está tu sistema y recién ahí se puede responder tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT fue creado para cambiar la presentación de un documento, no su contenido. Lo más cercano que puedes hacer es crear una transformación que elimine los nodos que no necesitas y reemplazar el documento original con el resultado, pero esa transformación bastante comienza de hacer en XSL

Lo que necesitas es una biblioteca XMLDOM para php o una base de datos XML (Basex por ejemplo)

Aquí va un ejemplo de [como hacerlo con XSLT](http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity#s6.):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="country"/>
```

Este template copia todos los elementos, excepto los `<country>`

Comment: Justamente eso es lo que quiero. Realizar una transformación que elimine los nodos que no necesito.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es un patrón que se conoce Identity Transform con filtros. En esta página lo encuentras bien documentado: http://www.xmlplease.com/xsltidentity

Comment: Existe alguna forma de realizarlo con PHP?

Es decir, si recibo como parámetro el uri en un documento PHP, ¿puedo eliminar todo el nodo planeación?

Cabe señalar que uri es unica para cada registro <planeacion>

Answer (score 0):

En XSLT puedes declarar un parámetro global:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="uri" select="'/PLAN/Datos/xml/planeacion/2151123-16-P-CI01.xml'"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="planeacion">
        <xsl:if test="not(uri = $uri)">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Con PHP, antes de utilizar el XSLT, puedes establecer el valor del parámetro: http://php.net/manual/es/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php: `setParameter('', 'uri', '/PLAN/Datos/xml/planeacion/2151075-15-P-CD02.xml')`.